# Perfomance difference between Open GL and UI kit for a map based application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, opengl-es

I am currently working on a navigation based app which uses third party maps. I use a lot of tiling. Though the maps are of very high resolution, I estimate an average of 6 tiles each of 256 * 256 pixels loaded . I might refresh the tiles like once in five minutes. I am currently using UIScrollview + tiles...

Should I really switch to Open GL ? I am hestitant to use Open GL because all the zoom functions and scrolling have to be hard coded in case of Open Gl.

Could some one please suggest the performance difference I would have?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any Apple development experience, but I think this falls under the more general practice of avoiding premature optimization. I'd say go ahead and implement it as simply and naturally as possible. If you (or the app store overlords) find that it has performance issues, then it might be worth the extra investment of time.

Be sure to structure your code with modularity in mind. Develop your own simple interface for displaying the GUI from the core program logic. Then, once you decide to switch, you should be able to develop an OpenGL replacement to drop in, using the same interface.